# how to setup Elmah for asp.net 1.1?

Tags: asp.net, elmah

I am trying to setup elmah for asp.net 1.1 application.
i have following entry in my web.config

```
<httpHandlers>
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </httpHandlers>

    <httpModules>
        <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
    </httpModules>

<configSections>
   <sectionGroup name="elmah">
        <section name="security" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah"/>
        <section name="errorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
        <section name="errorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
        <section name="errorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
   </sectionGroup>
```

did i missing anything?

Comment: It would be helpful to add the error you are getting.

Comment: Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized configuration section 'configSections'

Source Error: 


Line 11:   </httpModules>
Line 12:     
Line 13:     <configSections>
Line 14:     <sectionGroup name="elmah">
Line 15:    <section name="security" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah"/>
 

Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\LearnElmah\web.config    Line: 13

Answer (score 1):

We need to log error into XML files and it should be available from remote location. my web.config looks

```
<configSections>
   <sectionGroup name="elmah">
        <section name="security" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah"/>
        <section name="errorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
        <section name="errorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
        <section name="errorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
   </sectionGroup>
```

```
    <httpModules>
        <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
    </httpModules>
    <!--
    <elmah>
        <security allowRemoteAccess="yes" />        
        <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\LearnElmah\App_Data\Elmah" />
    </elmah>
    -->

<!--  DYNAMIC DEBUG COMPILATION
      Set compilation debug="true" to enable ASPX debugging.  Otherwise, setting this value to
      false will improve runtime performance of this application. 
      Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging symbols (.pdb information)
      into the compiled page. Because this creates a larger file that executes
      more slowly, you should set this value to true only when debugging and to
      false at all other times. For more information, refer to the documentation about
      debugging ASP.NET files.
-->

<compilation 
     defaultLanguage="c#"
     debug="true"
/>

<!--  CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGES
      Set customErrors mode="On" or "RemoteOnly" to enable custom error messages, "Off" to disable. 
      Add <error> tags for each of the errors you want to handle.

      "On" Always display custom (friendly) messages.
      "Off" Always display detailed ASP.NET error information.
      "RemoteOnly" Display custom (friendly) messages only to users not running 
       on the local Web server. This setting is recommended for security purposes, so 
       that you do not display application detail information to remote clients.
-->
<customErrors 
mode="Off" 
/> 

<!--  AUTHENTICATION 
      This section sets the authentication policies of the application. Possible modes are "Windows", 
      "Forms", "Passport" and "None"

      "None" No authentication is performed. 
      "Windows" IIS performs authentication (Basic, Digest, or Integrated Windows) according to 
       its settings for the application. Anonymous access must be disabled in IIS. 
      "Forms" You provide a custom form (Web page) for users to enter their credentials, and then 
       you authenticate them in your application. A user credential token is stored in a cookie.
      "Passport" Authentication is performed via a centralized authentication service provided
       by Microsoft that offers a single logon and core profile services for member sites.
-->
<authentication mode="Windows" /> 

<!--  AUTHORIZATION 
      This section sets the authorization policies of the application. You can allow or deny access
      to application resources by user or role. Wildcards: "*" mean everyone, "?" means anonymous 
      (unauthenticated) users.
-->

<authorization>
    <allow users="*" /> <!-- Allow all users -->
        <!--  <allow     users="[comma separated list of users]"
                         roles="[comma separated list of roles]"/>
              <deny      users="[comma separated list of users]"
                         roles="[comma separated list of roles]"/>
        -->
</authorization>

<!--  APPLICATION-LEVEL TRACE LOGGING
      Application-level tracing enables trace log output for every page within an application. 
      Set trace enabled="true" to enable application trace logging.  If pageOutput="true", the
      trace information will be displayed at the bottom of each page.  Otherwise, you can view the 
      application trace log by browsing the "trace.axd" page from your web application
      root. 
-->
<trace
    enabled="false"
    requestLimit="10"
    pageOutput="false"
    traceMode="SortByTime"
    localOnly="true"
/>

<!--  SESSION STATE SETTINGS
      By default ASP.NET uses cookies to identify which requests belong to a particular session. 
      If cookies are not available, a session can be tracked by adding a session identifier to the URL. 
      To disable cookies, set sessionState cookieless="true".
-->
<sessionState 
        mode="InProc"
        stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424"
        sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes"
        cookieless="false" 
        timeout="20" 
/>

<!--  GLOBALIZATION
      This section sets the globalization settings of the application. 
-->
<globalization 
        requestEncoding="utf-8" 
        responseEncoding="utf-8"
```

/>

Comment: Is this an answer, or clarification of your question?

Answer (score 0):

You also need the elmah section that defines the type of logger you are going to use, and, depending on which logger you use, possibly a connectionstring :

```
<elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="yes" />        
    <!--<errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data/Elmah" />-->
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="elmah" applicationName="MyApp" />
</elmah>

<connectionStrings>
    <add name="elmah" connectionString="" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: i am getting following error

<httpModules>
Line 23:    <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
Line 24:   </httpModules>

Comment: Parser Error Message: The format of the file 'Elmah' is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

this is a very late entry but anyone trying to set up ELMAH with .NET 1.1 and Visual Studio 2003, browse to following location:

https://code.google.com/p/elmah/source/browse/samples/web.config?repo=1x&r=c1d14a9e1626b74a4a606bae8bf9ae829ec641c5